# How does sleep() method work on given thread and output?

Tags: java, multithreading

I understand that `sleep()` is used to sleep a thread for specified time. I made tow examples - in  example 1 I am getting output as `1`,`2`, `3`,`4` because I created only one. In example 2, I created 2 instances of the thread and I'm getting output `1`,`1`,`2`,`2`,`3`,`3`,`4`,`4`.

Why the output is not `1`,`2`, `3`, `4` for the first thread followed by `1`,`2`,`3`,`4` for the second one?.

Example 1:

```
// Using sleep() method
  public class Aaa extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
        try{
           Thread.sleep(500); 
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Aaa m1=new Aaa();
        m1.start();
    }
  }

Output:
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

Example 2:

```
    // Using sleep() method
  public class Aaa extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
        try{
           Thread.sleep(500); // sleeps thread
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){        
       Aaa m1=new Aaa(); // creating one object
       Aaa m2=new Aaa(); // creating second object of a class
       m1.start(); // calls run method
       m2.start();
    }
  }


Output:
    1
    1
    2
    2
    3
    3
    4
    4
```

Comment: Consider naming conventions while you are naming.

Comment: @Code Enthusiastic- Okay, I am sorry!

Comment: `sleep()` doesn't 'give output' at all. Please clarify your title and question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have created two `Runnable` objects. If you run them by calling their `run` method you would get what you imagine:

```
   Aaa m1=new Aaa(); // creating one object
   Aaa m2=new Aaa(); // creating second object of a class
   System.out.println("Calling m1.run()");
   m1.run(); // we call run method
   System.out.println("Calling m2.run()");
   m2.run();
```

Output

```
Calling m1.run()
1
2
3
4
Calling m2.run()
1
2
3
4
```

because the method executes twice, one after the other.

Note that calling the `run` method of a `Runnable/Thread` is **not** the normal way to run a thread. You would normally use the `start` method.

If, however, you put each one in a `Thread` and `start` them:

```
   Aaa m1=new Aaa(); // creating one object
   Aaa m2=new Aaa(); // creating second object of a class
   System.out.println("Calling m1.start()");
   m1.start(); // thread calls run method
   System.out.println("Calling m2.start()");
   m2.start();
```

each object is now run in its own thread **in parallel** so the output is interleaved:

```
Calling m1.start()
Calling m2.start()
1 < From thread 1
1 < From thread 2
2 ...
2
3
3
4
4
```

The order could obviously vary depending on how the threads interleave.

One thing that may be confusing you is that you have chosen to `extend Thread`. This is discouraged. It is better to `implement Runnable` - like this:

```
public class Aaa implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(500); // sleeps thread
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Aaa m1 = new Aaa(); // creating one object
    Thread t1 = new Thread(m1); // Its thread
    Aaa m2 = new Aaa(); // creating second object of a class
    Thread t2 = new Thread(m2); // Its thread
    t1.start(); // calls m's run method in a new thread.
    t2.start();
  }

}
```

Now it is clearer that your objects are being run in two different threads and therefore run in parallel.

Comment: Also if he used an unsynchronized print method, the output might appear different.

Comment: @Mauren - Correct - but confusing for a beginner.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon How those two objects are `runnable`?

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic - because they `extend Thread` which `implements Runnable`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon- It is very clear now and thanks for your kind reply!

Answer (score 1):

Two threads are working simultaneously - it is the main point of thread usage. If you want something to be done not on main thread - you launch a new one. Or two if two tasks need to be executed and each of them works on it's own thread not waiting for another one.

Comment: Iam sorry, understood a bit but I dont understand clearly because Iam just beginner. If you say me clearly then I will learn it practically and would be helpful in my career also!

Answer (score 1):

m1 and m2 gets the same priority from the main thread and working concurrently.
sleep() allows the thread to go to block state for x milliseconds. When a thread goes into sleep state it doesn’t release the lock.

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired output 1,2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 use the join() method.
You can control the thread execution using this method.

`Aaa m1=new Aaa();` // creating one object
`Aaa m2=new Aaa();` // creating second object of a class
m1.start(); // calls run method
`m1.join()`;
     `m2.start();`

Answer (score 0):

sleep will suspend the execution for the specific time period. This is the efficient way to make the cpu available for other threads to run in parallel. Sleep will not release the lock. But need to take care that invoking sleep doesn't mean that the thread will be suspended for the time given.